# Data Cleaning with R

Tags: r, data-cleaning

Hey Stackoverflow community! I am having a little trouble with cleaning some data in R. I have variables that have semicolon's. For example,

```
Age   Job         Marital Education Default Balance Housing Loan Contact Day 
1 58; management  married  tertiary      no  ;2143;     yes   no unknown ;5;
2 44; technician  single secondary      no    ;29;     yes   no unknown ;5;   
3 33; entrepreneur married secondary      no     ;2;     yes  yes unknown ;5;   
4 47;  blue-collar married   unknown      no  ;1506;     yes   no unknown ;5;   
5 33;      unknown  single   unknown      no     ;1;      no   no unknown ;5;   
6 35;   management married  tertiary      no   ;231;     yes   no unknown ;5;
```

There are a total of 45,211 rows. I am stuck on figuring out how to go about removing all of the semicolon's in my df.

Comment: If you are reading the table with ```read.table``` or some other function of the same family, you could declare that ';' as the ```comment.char``` and it will be automatically desapear together to whatever is behind it, which in your case is nothing.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I do have columns after the age column

Comment: Ok, in that case the trick won't work :P, deleted my answer, Nicolas' seems reasonable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you can use `transform` to clean all affected columns in one go:

```
clean.data = transform(dirty.data, 
               Age = as.integer(gsub(";","",Age),
               Balance = as.integer(gsub(";","",Balance)), 
               Day = as.integer(gsub(";","",Day)))
```

Comment: This did it in all one simple step. Thanks!! @Valentin

Answer (score 1):

You have a lot of options with REGEX functions. Among them, gsub will do it. If

```
DF <- gsub(";","",DF)
```

Comment: Gotcha, I am somewhat new to R and those REGEX functions are a bit tricky

Comment: Perhaps you can cast it into integers with ```as.integer```

Comment: I edited the answer to reflect the expanded data frame. Note that in this particular way, all ";" will be suppressed. If you have legitimate ";" within your text strings, you will loose them too.

Answer (score 1):

If you already have a dataframe, you might be interested in the gsub() function.

so in your case:

```
 gsub(';', '', df$age)
```

As you can infer, this function strips any letter or symbol (here it's a semi-colon) from the vector that you specify.